# ¿Cómo eliminar un nodo div dependiendo del estado del chekbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const lista = document.querySelector(".lista");
            document.querySelector('.boton').addEventListener('click',()=>{
                let texto = document.querySelector(".input");
                if(texto.value == ""){
                     return alert("No estas escribiendo nada");
                }
                let insertar = `<div class="divGEnerated"><input class="chek" type="checkbox">${texto.value}</div>`
                lista.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",insertar);
                texto.value = '';
            });
            document.querySelector(".botonDelete").addEventListener('click',()=>{
                  
               });
```

```css
*{
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
        .lista{
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .lista > div{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 48, 104);
            color:white;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border:1px solid white;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .input{
            height: 30px;
            width: 300px;
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="datos">
            <input type="text" class="input">
            <button class="boton">Agregar</button>
            <button class="botonDelete">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="lista">
                <div>Texto</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

hola a todos, el contexto es el siguiente, estoy intentando hacer una lista de tareas básica y necesito que los las etiquetas div se eliminen por medio de un boton "eliminar" solo si el checkbox que tienen como hijo esta marcado, use insertAdjacentHTML para agregarlos al contenedor "lista",que metodo me pueden recomendar, soy algo nuevo en este mundo de programación y en JavaScript y aquí en stackoverflow así que cualquier consejo lo agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Quieres presionar eliminar y que se eliminen todos los checkbox marcados??

Comment: Exactamente amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const lista = document.querySelector(".lista");
document.querySelector('.boton').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    let texto = document.querySelector(".input");
    if(texto.value == ""){
            return alert("No estas escribiendo nada");
    }
    let insertar = `<div class="divGEnerated"><input class="chek" type="checkbox">${texto.value}</div>`
    lista.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",insertar);
    texto.value = '';
});

document.querySelector(".botonDelete").addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".divGEnerated").forEach((element) =>{
        if (element.querySelector(".chek")?.checked) {
            element.remove();
        }
    });      
});
```

```css
*{
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
        .lista{
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .lista > div{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 48, 104);
            color:white;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border:1px solid white;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .input{
            height: 30px;
            width: 300px;
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="datos">
            <input type="text" class="input">
            <button class="boton">Agregar</button>
            <button class="botonDelete">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="lista">
                <div>Texto</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Buscas todos .divGEnerated y recorres, luego preguntas por su hijo (.chek) si está chekeado y remueves

Comment: ahora lo entiendo, muchas gracias amigo me aclaraste muchas dudas! :D

Comment: @AntonyAcostaLeonelGranados Marcala como correcta entonces. Suerte!!